# Combining v-for with v-show on same element in template

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to display a list of entries, and I have it working up through retrieving JSON from a server, parsing it, storing it in a `Vuex.Store` and iterating through it with `v-for-"entry in this.$store.state.entries"`.

When a user first visits the page all entries will be visible. The next step is to filter the entries so that only matching entries remain visible. Since this filtering will be changing a lot, I want to use `v-show`. I have a separate component that lets users enter search terms, the server is queried, and an array of numbers—matching IDs—is returned. I want to only show entries with IDs that match the numbers in the array, `queriedEntries`.  My template is below:

```
<template>
    <div id="entries">
        <div v-for="entry in this.$store.state.entries"
            v-html="entry.content"
            v-show="this.$store.state.queriedEntries.includes(entry.id)">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I get an error that I don't understand, and searching for answers hasn't yielded anything because it doesn't match the problem others have had.

`[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this is undefined"`

It's the `this` in the `v-show`, but every other `this` works. What's up?

Comment: Just remove the `this` from your `v-show`. `this` is implied in templates.

Comment: It's also unnecessary in your `v-for`. I suspect it works in the `v-for` because that directive is handled slightly differently that the expressions of other directives. In most cases, however, you don't use `this` in a template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing `this` from everything but the `v-for`, as suggested, and the code worked. Why `this` causes an error in `v-show` and `v-html` is still a mystery.

Final, working code:

```
<div v-for="(entry, entryindex) in this.$store.state.entries"
 v-bind="{id:entryindex}"
 v-bind:key="entryindex" 
 v-show="$store.state.queryMatchedEntries[0] == -1 || $store.state.queryMatchedEntries.indexOf(parseInt(entryindex)) != -1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is occurring because you are referencing `this` inside your template. This is not necessary.

The first thing I recommend you do is have a read into Vuex' [Getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html). Further down on the same page, you'll find information about [mapGetters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper). This will help to prevent you from directly targeting/modifying data within your state. Modification of data should be left only to [Mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html) and [Actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html).

For example, your code may look like the below:

```
// in your component script
...
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      allEntries: 'entries', // map state.entries to the name 'allEntries'
      queriedEntries, // your other state value. You may want to convert this to a getter
      // other state values if necessary
    })
  }
}
...


// in your component template
<template>
    <div id="entries">
        <div v-for="entry in allEntries"
            v-html="entry.content"
            v-show="queriedEntries.includes(entry.id)">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
...
```

Here you can see that we have used [mapState](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper) which helpfully generates computed getter functions from our data in the store. We can then use the property name we have assigned it to within our template.

Comment: Yes, I know about using getters and other things regarding Vuex. Directly referencing this.$store.state.xxx was in published guides I've read, and I know not to directly modify values in the store.

Can you point me to info about when to use and not use `this`? Why does `this` work in the `v-for` but not in the same line in `v-show`?

Comment: You only need to use `this` inside your scripts. You don't need to use it inside your template at all. Maybe it's worth marking this answer as correct as it resolved your issue?